# Correct or most valuable way to model consumption/usage among users of a product or system?

Tags: modeling, model, mean

Is there a best method for approximating average daily consumption among users of a product? I'll use an example to illustrate.

We have monthly data for the past year (we have all data since launch) on the two following variables:

- Number of ice cream makers sold
- Number of ice cream maker mixes sold

We can assume when someone buys the maker they start using it right away. If we wanted to look at the average daily consumption among the months and among the year is there a best way to do so?

Would you do: 
(Ice cream mix sold in M1)/(Cumulative ice cream makers sold in M1) for each month over the period?

Is it better to average the values for the month and the previous period? And what would be the best way to calculate the average daily usage for the year?

Comment: "Better" depends on your objective.  The meaning of "average" does, too, because there are many kinds of averages. What do you want this average to represent?  What does it need to tell you about consumption?  How will you use this value?

Comment: The goal would be to see if usage of the ice cream maker is growing or declining over time. I should have clarified - average should represent whether or not usage of product is growing or declining over time. At a monthly level it would probably give some sense of seasonality, but the main goal would be to see that if over time - due to whatever market factors - per maker usage has increased. Maybe a better term would be attachment rate?